# How can I detect states of other objects

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using P5.js. 
I'm trying to make a program that allows the user to click on squares and the block closest to the bottom that is not already black will turn black. The code I'm using either turns all the squares in the first column black. I've tried using return(false) but that just causes the bottom square to turn black.

```js
let squares = []
let squareNum = 0
let rows;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 900)
  background(100)
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    rows = i + 1
    for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      let x = i * 150
      let y = j * 150
      squares[squareNum] = new Square(x, y, 'gray');
      squareNum++
    }
  }
}

function mousePressed() {
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    if (mouseX > squares[i].x && mouseX < squares[i].x + squares[i].size && mouseY > squares[i].y && mouseY < squares[i].y + squares[i].size) {
      if (i < 6) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
          if (squares[5 - j].colour = 'gray') {
            squares[5 - j].colour = 'black'
            print(5 - j + ' is now black')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function draw() {
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].show();
  }
}

class Square {
  constructor(x, y, colour) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.size = 150
    this.colour = colour
  }
  show() {
    fill(this.colour)
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please clearify the usecase. Are you trying to turn black all the bottom boxes from the position you clicked?

Comment: I'm trying to turn the box closest to the bottom under the clicked box black

Comment: Clicking on `box[0][0]` should turn `box[n][0]` black, Clicking on `box[2][3]` should trun `box[n][3]` black. right? (n represents the last row)

Comment: Not yet. I've only put in the code for the first column.

Comment: @ethan-hermsey I'm still confused on what he's trying to achieve

Comment: @EthanHermsey that makes sure that the box that is clicked is in the first column.

Comment: @JimishFotariya basically i want to make a simple 2d sandbox game with a gravity effect so that only either the bottom squares or boxes with black squares below them can turn black

Comment: First, you should modify you code and make a 2d array of tiles. which will help you think more clearly. 
then for any clicked `tile(i,j)`  you just need to iterate incrementing `j` with `1`, which will give you all bottom tiles one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean it like this?

```js
let squares = []
// Added variables to avoid fixed numbers in the code.
// Note: This was 150 originally. Changed to be able to print it on the screen.
let squareSize = 30;
let rowCount = 6;
let columnCount = 6;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(squareSize * columnCount, squareSize * rowCount);
  background(100)
  for (let i = 0; i < columnCount; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < rowCount; j++) {
      let x = i * squareSize
      let y = j * squareSize
      squares.push(new Square(x, y, 'gray'));
    }
  }
}

// Check whether the mouse is currently within a specific square.
function isMouseInSquare(square, mouseX, mouseY) {
  // NOTE: brackets help a lot to understand logical expressions and to avoid bugs.
  return (mouseX > square.x && mouseX < (square.x + square.size)) && (mouseY > square.y && mouseY < (square.y + square.size))
}

// Returns the squares for a given column based on their x postion - starting with the one closest to the bottom.
function getSameColumnSquares(square) {
  return squares.filter(s => s.x === square.x).reverse();
}

function mousePressed() {
  let pressedSquare = squares.find(square => isMouseInSquare(square, mouseX, mouseY));
  let squaresInColumn = getSameColumnSquares(pressedSquare);
  let firstNonBlackSquare = squaresInColumn.find(square => square.colour !== "black");
  if (firstNonBlackSquare) {
    firstNonBlackSquare.colour = "black";
  }
}

function draw() {
  for (let i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
    squares[i].show();
  }
}

class Square {
  constructor(x, y, colour) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.size = squareSize;
    this.colour = colour
  }
  show() {
    fill(this.colour)
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. :) I just modified the `mousePressed`method, because I think it using the standard array functions improve the readability.